# Apollo GraphQL: Augment instead of overriding default resolver behaviour

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

In the Apollo Server documentation, it describes the behaviour of the [default resolver](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/data/#default-resolvers), which is quite handy.

I also gathered from somewhere else (another SO question if I recall), that you can override the default resolver function with your own, by passing a fieldResolver function into the options for the apollo-server instance:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers,
  fieldResolver: function (source, args, context, info) {
    console.log("Field resolver triggered!")
    return null;
  }
});
```

What I would like to do is augment the default behaviour, rather than overriding it. Specifically, I am integrating with a REST API that returns fields in snake_case, whereas my schema is attempting to follow the advised convention of using camelCase for field names. I would like to wrap this field name conversion around the default resolver behaviour, rather than having to re-write it.

Alternatively, if somebody can point me to the source location for the default resolver implementation, I'd be happy enough to take that and adapt it either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default resolver is available through the `graphql` module:

```
const { defaultFieldResolver } = require('graphql')
```

However, converting a field from snake case to camel case can be done without calling the default resolver:

```
someField: (parent) => parent.some_field
```

If you want to create a reusable resolver function, you can do something like:

```
const camelCaseResolver = (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
  return parent[_.snakeCase(info.fieldName)]
}
```

Or better yet, extract the logic into a [schema directive](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives):

```
class SnakeCaseDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    field.resolve = async function (parent, args, ctx, info) {
      return parent[_.snakeCase(info.fieldName)]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: More than I could have hoped for. Thankyou!

Comment: Hi @Daniel, having played with this, I'm now wondering if the above directive can be applied globally without having to add `@snakeCase` to every field in my (extensive) schema. Any wisdom you can add?

Comment: My preference would be to wrap the calls to the REST API with a function that would traverse the response and modify all the fields to camelCase. That's what I ended up doing on a recent project that dealt with the same issue.

Comment: Outside of that, off the top of my head... You could monkey patch the `defaultFieldResolver` or generate the schema then iterate through all the types and modify the resolver for any field that uses the default resolver.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good array of options there. I think perhaps your own approach of converting the fields within the RESTDataSource implementation is probably the best one for my needs also.

Comment: @DanielRearden , how do I monkey patch defaultfieldresover? Your help is greatly appreciated